# How to route subdomain i laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes, subdomain

[image]I work with laravel for a few weeks, but now I don't know how to config subdomain. 
I have name of my side : http://originalsite.nameofproject.pl and I want, when I open this site to be in URL like this : http://nameofproject.mysubdomain.pl.

I didn't add nothing in my routes. Only config everything on my hosting.

Now I have errors like this when I enter my subdomain adress in URL:

Warning: require(//../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /index.php on line 22

Warning: require(//../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /index.php on line 22

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '//../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/:/usr/local/php/pear7') in /index.php on line 22

I don't know totally what I should do next.

Answer (score 0):

I explain what can you do it's not best answer but work well

1.create subdomain like blog

after that in public_html or www you have blog folder

2.before public_html create some folder like laravel/doc and upload laravel files into this directory

3.move public directory to public_html/blog

4.in public_html/blog edit index.php 
and in fist lines change your bootstrap path

```
require __DIR__.'/../../laravel/doc/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

and

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel/doc/bootstrap/app.php';
```

5.after that add this:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
return __DIR__;
```

});

and run blog.yoursite.com
is working well

hope helping to you

Comment: I add my structure on serwer and I think I've lost... I created subdomain ("my_subdomain_name"). As you can see I have blog folder. Now i should add new folder before blog or laravel?

Answer (score 0):

I found in documentation sth like this:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'], function () {
Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
    //
});
});
```

Maybe is a possibility to use this to work my subdomain? I really don't know what is $account and $id...